# Keyboard freezes when xorg crashes

Tags: xorg, keyboard, graphics, freeze

Situation is like that. Many times has happened that Xorg freezes and with it also keyboard. Quite some times because of some Compiz effects or Flash (fullscreen switch).
Keyboard becomes totaly unresponsive, while mouse still works (I can move cursor, but can't click since desktop freezes) and music still plays and I can connect trough ssh. This is the only way I know I can try to solve problem - either by killing browser&flash or lastly restarting xorg server.

This problem appears on more than one Ubuntu computer. My home dekstop with proprietery nvidia driver, on my work where I use noveau driever (opensource driver for geforce) and sometimes *(but rarely)* also on laptop with ATI graphics *(using r300g driver which is really good!).*

**Can someone explains why mouse still works while I can't input from keyboard?** *(I can't switch to virtual console or do R-E-I-S-U-B command)* I have USB keyboard and USB mouse.

Comment: just to double-check, you are also holding the ctrl-alt-prntscrn keys while pressing reisub sequentially? i've never had a freeze that i couldn't get out of w/ the magic keys.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment. Sorry, nothing. Neither Num Lock led does not respond...

Comment: Can you replicate the problem with a PS/2 keyboard?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

This has been affecting me also. Sometimes the mouse still works, sometimes not. Keyboard never responds. Most times, I can ssh into my machine and killall -9 chrome and the system will return to normal. Now trying Firefox to replicate the problem.
(Btw, I intended this just as a comment to the question, but I cannot figure out how to do it)

Comment: My problem is that xorg hangs. It uses 100% cpu and usually does not help if I kill other aplications.

Comment: xorg hangs for me too at cpu100. I've noticed it's only done it for me with chrome running. And killing chrome / compiz or anything else sometimes helps. Not always though. It's mostly reboot time when it happens.